# How to throw exception and abort to publish an item in event handler

Tags: publishing, event-system, c#

I want to stop publishing a structure groups for certain user groups. I'm able to catch the structure group and filter per the desired groups, but when I throw the exception, nothing happens and the structure group is sent to the publish queue.

```
    private void SubScribe()
    {
        EventSystem.Subscribe<StructureGroup, PublishOrUnPublishEventArgs>(OnPublishTransactionPublish, EventPhases.Initiated);
    }

    private void OnPublishTransactionPublish(StructureGroup structureGroup, PublishOrUnPublishEventArgs e, EventPhases phase)
    {
        if (structureGroup == null)
            return;

        // get the person who created the publish transaction (= the one who published the item)
        var creator = new User(structureGroup.Session.AccessToken.Id, structureGroup.Session);
        var groups = creator.GroupMemberships;
        var structureGroupId = structureGroup.Id.ItemId.ToString();

        if (structureGroupId == tcmHomeStructureGroup)
        {
            if (!groups.Where(x => x.Group.Title == homeAllowedGroup).Any())
            {
                ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("MijnPostNL.Tridion.Addons", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
                throw new PublisherException(new LocalizableMessage(rm, "cannotPublish", new object[] { structureGroup.Id }));
            }
        }
        if (structureGroupId == tcmPersoneelsinfoStructureGroup)
        {
            if (groups.Where(x => personeelsinfoNotAllowedGroups.Contains(x.Group.Title)).Any())
            {
                throw new PublisherException(new LocalizableMessage(Resources.ResourceManager, "cannotPublish", new object[] { structureGroup.Id }));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try just "Exception"  instead of "PublisherException"?

Comment: You ought to be able to see the exception in the Windows Event Viewer. Can you confirm this?

Comment: I cannot imagine that nothing happens when you throw an exception. You might get fooled because your event handler isn’t loaded in the apropriate hosts yet (in case of CME, you should restart the TCM Service Host).

Comment: BTW: you should use `Session.AccessToken` directly rather than loading a new `User` object by ID (in that way you loose the expanded group memberships).